# Implement F5 key using html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the following piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-     revalidate">
<meta http-eq`enter code here`uiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"> 
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="Sun, 26 Jul 2015 23:12:00 GMT"> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Headi</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And also have tried the implementation of location.reload(true) code, both     dint work in my case i.e they are working to reload the page but not actually refreshing it. The output prints the body initially but after 10 sec is a blank page :(

i want to implement functionality of F5 through script and  not reload.

Comment: please add some details like your codes

Comment: I have to implement this in my project no such other code

Comment: I have used the following code:<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-     revalidate">
<meta http-eq`enter code here`uiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"> 
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="Sun, 26 Jul 2015 23:12:00 GMT"> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"> 
</head>

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the URL after the "10" in content:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=http://www.example.com/index.html">
```

Comment: I have tried this but this will redirect to specific page but i want to refresh the  current page

Comment: But your "current" page must have an address, too?

Comment: Yes but that address will keep on changing. How do i handle that?